# send email from wamp and proxy

Tags: php, proxy, wamp, sendmail

it's two days that I'm trying to send email from my php application running on my PC with WAMP. 
I modified the php.ini in this way:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = mail.myisp.org
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 26

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = admin@myisp.org
auth_username = admin@myisp.org
auth_password = mySuperSecretPWD
```

When I try to send an email I get this error:

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver
```

I also tried with win sendmail but it time out every time. The reason is that I'm behind a proxy. Infact this is working:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:3128');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla...');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
var_dump($result);
var_dump($info);
var_dump($error);
curl_close($ch);
```

How can I set wamp to use the proxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
smtp_port = 26
```

looks incorrect. Usually, SMTP runs on port `25`. Is your smtp server running on port `26`?

Can you actually ping the server? You can try to telnet to `mail.myisp.org` and use port `25` or `26` and see if you can connect.

Check also your Internet Properties. Go to Connections tab, LAN settings and put your proxy server settings there.